# Full authentication is required to access this resource after enable CSRF

Tags: javascript, spring, svelte

stack: Java spring boot, svelte

I received message "403 Full authentication is required to access this resource" after I enable CSRF
How do I check or debug which made that error?

Here is step that produce error

1. When I sign in application, web app send request to "GET {api server}/csrf"
   this is response from endpoint

   ```
    {
     "token":"d4cb2245-be82-4b61-ace5-8d52c6068182",
     "parameterName":"_csrf",
     "headerName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN"
    }
   ```
2. I collect response.token and add it to "X-XRF-TOKEN"
   this is header when sending request to "POST {api server}/auth/signin"
   [request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcOUW.png)

I follow step 4. (4.1, 4.2) https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf

1. This is Security configure on my side

   ```
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.cors().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
               .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
               .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"**").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/csrf").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated();
       http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
   }
   ```

   It works if I set Security Config like this

   ```
   http.csrf().disable()
   ```
2. I add GET /csrf for collecting CSRF token

   ```
   @RestController
   public class CsrfController {

       @GetMapping("/csrf")
       public CsrfToken csrf(CsrfToken token) {
           return token;
       }
   }
   ```
3. For front-end side I add function which is fire the "/csrf"

   ```
   function getCsrf(headers) {
     return request('/csrf', 'get', null, headers)
     .then(response => {
       return response;
     });
   }
   ```

   ```
   function post(url, data, headers) {
     return getCsrf(headers)
     .then(resp => {
       headers = {
         ...headers,
         'X-XSRF-TOKEN': resp.token,
       }

       return request(url, 'post', data, headers);
     });
   }
   ```
4. The way to prove that is not related with "Authorization" header. I was try to add "Authorization" to request header with valid token. I still got the same error

   ```
   function post(url, data, headers) {
     return getCsrf(headers)
     .then(resp => {
       headers = {
         ...headers,
         'X-XSRF-TOKEN': resp.token,
         'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
       }

       return request(url, 'post', data, headers);
     });
   }
   ```

Update 7 Dec 2022 11:58

I add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`

I found some error message

```
2022-12-07 11:55:42,243 TRACE [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/13)
2022-12-07 11:55:42,243 TRACE [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/13)
2022-12-07 11:55:42,243 DEBUG [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-12-07 11:55:42,244 TRACE [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/13)
2022-12-07 11:55:42,244 TRACE [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: Invoking CorsFilter (4/13)
2022-12-07 11:55:42,244 TRACE [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: Invoking CsrfFilter (5/13)
2022-12-07 11:55:42,245 DEBUG [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter: Invalid CSRF token found for http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/signin
2022-12-07 11:55:42,245 DEBUG [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl: Responding with 403 status code
2022-12-07 11:55:42,245 TRACE [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter: Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2022-12-07 11:55:42,246 DEBUG [XNIO-1 task-2] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

look like I use invalid CSRF token.
But how do I get the valid CSRF token?

Update 7 Dec 2022 12:38

I try send request via POSTMAN with this it works fine.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/signin' \
--header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: b05438d7-530a-48fa-9b11-11de56b5a87a' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=b05438d7-530a-48fa-9b11-11de56b5a87a' \
--data-raw '{....}'
```

Look like request that web api send doesn't contains "Cookie" in request header

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by

1. Assign credentials to request header

   ```
   fetch(isUrl(url) ? url : `${apiBaseURL}${url}`, {
       method: 'post',
       headers: `${headers}`,
       credentials: 'include',
       body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : (body || null),
   })
   ```
2. Update CORS on back-end side

   ```
   public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://127.0.0.1:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
   ```